# VSTS Test Agent - IPC Port Access Denied

Tags: windows, powershell, port, powershell-remoting, microsoft-test-manager

My test agent and controller are communicating well. But, when agent machine has restarted the agent is going to offline. And it is coming "online" only when I remotely login into the machine.
To automate this, I tried PowerShell script. When I run my PS code on agent machine directly it is working fine and agent process is starting and it is communicating with the controller.
When I try to run from other machine, it is able to start the process `QTAgentProcessUI.exe`. But failing to launch the agent UI. When I look in to the Event Viewer logs, it is showing

> (QTDCAgent32.exe, PID 3780, Thread 1) DataCollectionAgentProcess: Failed to get agent process proxy: System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Failed to connect to an IPC Port: Access is denied.

How can we start agent process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\QTAgentProcessUI.exe" on remote test agent machine with PowerShell by overcoming the access denied issues with port 6910?

In my investigation, I found that the Post 6910 is closed.

I am able to find out a work around.
I created a VBS script and calling the PowerShell file in it. Then I created a scheduled task in Task Scheduler.
When I trigger this schudled task from other machine, it is working like a charm. It is able to start the agent process.

The credentials which I am using below is an administrator on that machine.

```
$Username = 'xxxxxx'
$Password = 'xxxxx'
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$pass

$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName "domain\machine1" -Credential $credentials

Invoke-Command -Session $s -Command {
    C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\StartTestAgent.ps1
}
```